# How to select total time from three time columns (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have table with columns of **time(0)** datatypes:

```
Name   TimeOne          TimeTwo          TimeThree
------ ---------------- ---------------- ----------------
Sarah  06:45:00         03:30:00         NULL
John   06:45:00         NULL             NULL
```

How to make SELECT statement so that the "CalculatedTotal" column is total from TimeOne, TimeTwo and TimeThree per row?

What I'd like to have is select query like this:

```
SELECT
    Name,
    TimeOne,
    TimeTwo,
    TimeThree,
    TimeOne + TimeTwo + TimeThree As CalculatedTotal
FROM 
    MyTable
```

I'd like to get back resultset like this:

```
Name   TimeOne          TimeTwo          TimeThree        CalculatedTotal
------ ---------------- ---------------- ---------------- ---------------
Sarah  06:45:00         03:30:00         NULL             10:15:00
John   06:45:00         NULL             NULL             06:45:00
```

Just using plus operator in select statement gives you an error:

*Operand data type **time** is invalid for add operator.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could determine the number of seconds for each `time` value, add them together and convert back to `time`:

```
select TimeOne, TimeTwo, TimeThree,
       cast(dateadd(s, isnull(datediff(s, 0, TimeOne), 0) + isnull(datediff(s, 0, TimeTwo), 0) + isnull(datediff(s, 0, TimeThree), 0), 0) as time(0)) as CalculatedTotal
from MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below script.

select convert(time, CONVERT(datetime, '00:08:00.000') + CONVERT(datetime, '00:07:00.000'))

select convert(time,cast('00:08:00.000'as datetime)+cast('00:07:00.000' as datetime) ) as 'T'

Answer (score -1):

I belive you can use the SUM() function

```
SELECT
    Name,
    TimeOne,
    TimeTwo,
    TimeThree,
    SUM(TimeOne+TimeTwo+TimeThree) As CalculatedTotal
FROM 
    MyTable
```

But equally you might need to convert each to seconds first using the SECOND() function, then use SEC_TO_TIME() on the result.

Edit: I've just had a look at the manual:

> The SUM() and AVG() aggregate functions do not work with temporal
>   values. (They convert the values to numbers, which loses the part
>   after the first nonnumeric character.) To work around this problem,
>   you can convert to numeric units, perform the aggregate operation, and
>   convert back to a temporal value. Examples:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(time_col))) FROM tbl_name;
SELECT FROM_DAYS(SUM(TO_DAYS(date_col))) FROM tbl_name;
```

Comment: SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(col1)+TIME_TO_SEC(col2))) AS col4 FROM `test` -- Showing rows 0 - 0 (~11 total, Query took 0.0004 sec) col4
27:10:34

Comment: Maybe if he was using MySQL.  Check out his tags, it's SQL Server.  That is not a function in SQL Server.

Comment: Fair point I hadn't spotted the tag or the end of the post title! My answer is indeed invalid then.